# If $(\mu_k^{\ast k})_k$ is tight, can we show that $(\mu_{kn}^{\ast k})_k$ is tight as well?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\mu_k$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ for $k\in\mathbb N$.

Assume $\left(\mu_k^{\ast k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is tight$^1$ and let $n\in\mathbb N$.

> Are we able to show that the family $$\nu_k:=\mu_{kn}^{\ast k}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$ is tight as well?

If $d=1$, we can easily prove the claim in the following way: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\left(\mu_k^{\ast k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is tight, there is a compact $K\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $$\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\mu_k^{\ast k}(K^c)<\varepsilon^n\tag1.$$ Choose $r>0$ such that $K\subseteq[-nr,nr]$ and hence $$\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\mu_k^{\ast k}([-nr,nr]^c)\le\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\mu_k^{\ast k}(K^c)<\varepsilon^n\tag2.$$ Now note that for $\eta:=\nu_k$ we've got \begin{equation}\begin{split}\eta((r,\infty))^n&=\eta^{\otimes n}((r,\infty)^n)\\&\le\eta^{\otimes n}\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\sum_{i=1}^nx_i>nr\right\}\right)\\&=\eta^{\ast n}\left(\left\{y\in\mathbb R:y>nr\right\}\right)\\&=\eta^{\ast n}((nr,\infty))<\varepsilon^n\end{split}\tag3\end{equation} and, analogously, $$\eta((-\infty,-r))^n\le\eta^{\ast n}(n(-\infty,-r))<\varepsilon^n\tag4.$$ Thus, we immediately obtain the claim.

> Can we generalize this?

*Remark*: I would also be interested in the claim when $\mathbb R^d$ is replaced by an arbitrary (complete, separable) normed $\mathbb R$-vector space (or pre-$\mathbb R$-Hilbert space).

### **EDIT**

Maybe there is a more elegant approach (which I really would like to know), but the same as above should work for arbitrary $d$: We agian choose $r>0$ such that $[-nr,nr]^d\subseteq K$. With $\eta$ as above, it is sufficient to show that the measure of $(r,\infty)\times\mathbb R^{d-1}$, $\mathbb R\times(r,\infty)\times\mathbb R^{d-2}$, and so on, is less than $\varepsilon$ (since the union of these sets is the complement of $[-r,r]^d$). As in $(3)$, we obtain, for example, \begin{equation}\begin{split}\eta((r,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d)^n&=\eta^{\otimes n}(((r,\infty)\times\mathbb R^{d-1})^n)\\&\le\eta^{\otimes n}\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb R^d:\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)_1>nr\right\}\right)\\&=\eta^{\ast n}\left(\left\{y\in\mathbb R^d:y_1>nr\right\}\right)\\&=\eta^{\ast n}((nr,\infty)\times\mathbb R^{d-1})<\varepsilon^n.\end{split}\tag5\end{equation}

> Any mistake in my reasoning above? And even if not: This approach obviously doesn't generalize to an infinite-dimensional normed $\mathbb R$-vector space. So, does anyone have an idea for an other approach which also works in that case?

---

$^1$ If $E$ is a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, then $$\theta_k:E^k\to E\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^kx_i$$ and if $\eta_i$ is a finite measure on $\mathcal B(E)$, then $$\eta_1\ast\cdots\ast\eta_k:=\theta_k(\eta_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\eta_k)$$ is the pushforward of the product measure $\eta_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\eta_k$ under $\theta_k$.

If $E$ is a Hausdorff space, then a family $\mathcal F$ of finite measures on a $\mathcal B(E)$ is called *tight* if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ such that $$\sup_{\eta\in\mathcal F}\eta(K^c)<\varepsilon.$$